# how to float the console of the debug area in xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

I would like to know if it is possible, and how to make the debug area console float when debugging, that is, when executing my program the output is in a system terminal window, and not in the internal xcode window , and be able to move the console to another monitor independently of the xcode window:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new Xcode window (**⇧⌘T**).
2. Make it show the debug area (**⇧⌘Y**).
3. Resize the debug area by dragging its divider all the way to the top.
4. Hide unnecessary navigators (**⌘0**) and inspectors (**⌥⌘0**).

That's it, you have a floating window showing just the debug area that you can drag to another display.

Comment: Your advice has been very helpful to me.